# Mapbox or Google Maps. Is this possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, mapbox

I have a custom map from a client. They want to either use Mapbox or google maps to add markers to it. The problem is they've customized how the world map actually looks. It doesn't show on the map image attached, but they cut off Alaska, and want to show it directly under Texas as a floating state. They also want to show so other states in an odd order. To the right of Alaska they want Hawaii, Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands.

Two issues here:

1) Can this be done? I can't find any information about cutting pieces of a map up by moving states around.

2) If I CAN do this, will the geocoding still work for the map? Cause now Alaska is way the heck down there.

[image]

Comment: I would not use that image; it's not projected like Google Maps projects the map.  Look at Google maps, you see vertical and horizontal lines, for example, the border with Canada (left side) must be a horizontal straight line, it must not be a curved line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, yes to both of your issues.

Now, to answer your issues:

**1) Can this be done? I can't find any information about cutting pieces of a map up by moving states around.**

As discussed in [Translate your project from Google to Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/help/google-to-mapbox/), you have options to customize maps and features. Then, any customized project created in the Mapbox Editor or uploaded from Mapbox Studio Classic will have a Map ID. Use the Map ID when initializing the map to add it as the active layer.

**2) If I CAN do this, will the geocoding still work for the map? Cause now Alaska is way the heck down there.**

Yes, geocoding will still work. With Mapbox, `L.mapbox.geocoder()` will gladly geocode your addresses.

Please try going through the given documentation for more information and for sample codes. Hope that helps!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you're saying I could overlay a 'real' map of the US with this graphic layer you see here? And Geocoding the yellow dots on the image layer will still work correctly?